# iOS app icon is not displayed in iDevices

Tags: ios, xcode8.2

Currently i'm developing applications using XCode 8.2,  I have added an app icon in the assets folder.But here, i'm able to see the app icon when i run it in simulator.  and when i run the same app in real device app icon disappears and some other image is displayed. I would like to know the reason for the issue i'm facing.

Comment: can you please post what kind of icon it's appear on real devices ?

Comment: its checkbox image which i have used in another screen

Comment: have you added app icon to assets with all required dimension and make sure ever dimension is as per the apple standard

Comment: yes .i have added the app icons with all correct dimensions.And moreover this is my fifth app i'm developing and this is the first time i'm getting this type of issue.

Comment: which real device are you using ??

Comment: iPhone 5S..OS:9.0.2

Comment: I figured it out.The UI designer had simply renamed his .psd files with .png and xcode thought this was fine. However, renaming the .pngs isn't going to automatically make them real .pngs. The way I solved this was going to mac preview and exporting the files to the PNG format.

Answer (score 0):

iOS caches the icon image. Change the system language to another language. You should see the icon change.